# Running Get-ChildItem on UNC path works in Powershell but not in Powershell run in batch file

Tags: batch-file, powershell, cmd, unc

I am writing a batch file that executes a Powershell script that at one point loops items with UNC paths as attributes and uses `Get-ChildItem` on those paths. In a minimal version, this is what is happening in my scripts:

**Master.bat**

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File "Slave.ps1"
```

**Slave.ps1**

```
$foo = @{Name = "Foo"}
$foo.Path = "\\remote-server\foothing"

$bar = @{Name = "Bar"}
$bar.Path = "\\remote-server\barthing"

@( $foo, $bar ) | ForEach-Object {
    $item = Get-ChildItem $_.Path
    # Do things with item
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that when I run **Master.bat**, it fails at `Get-ChildItem` with an error along the lines of

```
get-childitem : Cannot find path '\\remote-server\foothing' because it does not exist.
```

However, it seems to work perfectly fine if I run the **Slave.ps1** file directly using Powershell. Why might this be happening only when the **Master.bat** file is run?

**Things I have tried**

- Prepending the UNC paths with `FileSystem::` with providers http://powershell.org/wp/2014/02/20/powershell-gotcha-unc-paths-and-providers/
- Making sure there are no strange characters in the actual paths
- Using the `-literalPath` parameter instead of the plain `-path` parameter for `Get-ChildItem`
- Running `Get-ChildItem \\remote-server\foothing` in PowerShell and succeeding to verify connection to the remote server

Comment: How is the batch file being run? Are you just double clicking it to run it? Is it being run by the task scheduler? Is it your credentials that are running the script when the batch file is run?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician It's being run as an administrator by right clicking the .bat file then clicking 'Run as Administrator'

Comment: When running as administrator does it prompt for credentials? Do you get the same errors if you simply run the batch file instead of running it as administrator?

Comment: No difference between running as administrator and without. The error comes up regardless.

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you running? I am unable to replicate the issue using PowerShell v4 or v3

Comment: this is working fine on my station even with PS V2 `powershell -version 2 -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File "c:\temp\Slave.ps1"`

Comment: This works for me. Check the path/provider.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I have found this issue when running scripts referring to UNC paths - but the error only occurs when the root of the script is set to a non file system location. e.g. PS SQLSEVER\

So the following fails with the same error:

```
cd env:
$foo = @{Name = "Foo"}
$foo.Path = "\\remote-server\foothing"

$bar = @{Name = "Bar"}
$bar.Path = "\\remote-server\barthing"

@( $foo, $bar ) | ForEach-Object {
    $item = Get-ChildItem $_.Path
    # Do things with item
     Write-Host $item
}
```

So my resolution was to ensure that the PS prompt was returned to a file system location before executing this code. e.g.

```
cd env:
$foo = @{Name = "Foo"}
$foo.Path = "\\remote-server\foothing"

$bar = @{Name = "Bar"}
$bar.Path = "\\remote-server\barthing"

cd c: #THIS IS THE CRITICAL LINE
@( $foo, $bar ) | ForEach-Object {
    $item = Get-ChildItem $_.Path
    # Do things with item
     Write-Host $item
}
```

I hope this helps - I would be very happy with the bounty as this is my first answer on stack overflow.
P.S. I forgot to add - the PS command prompt root may be set by auto loaded modules in the configuration of your machine. I would check with Get-Location to see if you are actually executng from a non FileSystem location.

Comment: +1 You, sir, are a genius. I've spent bloody hours trying to figure out why this wasn't working for me!! Many thanks indeed.

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you!! I had the same Problem script was failing and kicking me back to PS SQLSEVER\.

Comment: +1 Very good, I do cd $pwd to not mess up other paths, but this was hard to find withouth your suggestion!

Comment: 7 years later - your still helping!!

Answer (score 14):

[Rory's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23625969/45375) provides an effective workaround, but there's **a solution that doesn't require changing the current location to a FileSystem provider location first**:

**Prefix your UNC paths with `FileSystem::`** to ensure that they are recognized correctly, irrespective of the current location:

```
$foo = @{
   Name = "Foo"
   Path = "FileSystem::\\remote-server\foothing"
}

$bar = @{
   Name = "Bar"
   Path = "FileSystem::\\remote-server\barthing"
}
```

---

Alternatively, here is a **tweak to Rory's answer** to **avoid changing the current location session-globally** (to preserve whatever the current location is), using `Push-Location` and `Pop-Location`:

```
try {
  # Switch to the *filesystem provider's* current location, whatever it is.
  Push-Location (Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem)

  # Process the paths.
  $foo, $bar | ForEach-Object {
      $item = Get-ChildItem $_.Path
      # Do things with item
  }
} finally {
   # Restore the previous location.
   Pop-Location
}
```

---

#### Optional background information

[This excellent blog post](https://powershell.org/2014/02/20/powershell-gotcha-unc-paths-and-providers/) explains the underlying problem (emphasis added):

> PowerShell doesn't recognize [UNC paths] as "rooted" because they're not on a PSDrive; as such, **whatever provider is associated with PowerShell's current location will attempt to handle them**.

Adding prefix `FileSystem::` unambiguously identifies the path as being a `FileSystem` provider path, irrespective of the provider underlying the current location.

Comment: I've been struggling for a while, your solution worked perfectly to me. Even though when I checked the line before with [System.IO.Directory]::Exists($path), I was having errors with Get-ChildItem -Path $path 
Adding FileSystem:: fixed it.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @kerzek. Yes, using `[System.IO.Directory]::Exists($path)` always works, because .NET _only_ knows about _filesystem_ paths, unlike PowerShell with its multiple drive providers.

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere else about the [`Push-Location`](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh849855.aspx) and [`Pop-Location`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849842.aspx) commands to counter this kind of problem - I landed on your question while manually, step-by-step, testing a new routine where the script has push/pop, but I forgot to do them on my PS window. After checking @Rory's answer I noticed I was on PS SQLServer:\ instead of PS C:\ prompt.

So a way to use this on your "slave" script would be:

```
$foo = @{Name = "Foo"}
$foo.Path = "\\remote-server\foothing"

$bar = @{Name = "Bar"}
$bar.Path = "\\remote-server\barthing"

@( $foo, $bar ) | ForEach-Object {
    $item = Get-ChildItem $_.Path
    Push-Location
    # Do things with item
    Pop-Location
}
```

Thought of adding the Push/Pop before and after the `# Do things` because it seems that it's those things that change the location.

Comment: While using `Push-Location` / `Pop-Location` to _temporarily_ switch to a filesystem location is a good idea, your solution won't work, because (a) your `Push-Location` command comes _after_ `Get-ChildItem`, which is where the error surfaces and (b), even if you changed the order, `Push-Location` without arguments just pushes the _current_ location onto the stack of remembered locations, it doesn't switch to a _filesystem_ location, which is what is needed here.